# I am looking for 'Programming+Electronics+ Physics' field

Tags: soft-question, education, computational-physics

I wish to pursue a career that somehow involves programming, electronics, and physics. What are such careers?

Also, I have heard of some 1 year post-graduate diplomas/courses for specialization in Physics. Which universities/ colleges offer them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **unclear what you' are asking**.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for experimental particle physics on a big detector at a national lab:

- There's no end to the custom electronics and embedded systems associated with the data acquisition,
- Computer science is definitely required (analysis of big data sets), and
- Plenty of really interesting fundamental physics.

If you are still at the university go talk to a professor at your institution who is involved with a particle physics experiment at something like CERN, DESY, or one of the other large labs depending on your country of origin (e.g. in America: BNL, ORNL, Los Alamos) and he/she can give you more guidance.

Good luck!